# WPF - Border template with content

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, border, contentcontrol

Let's assume I have the following control template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Test">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Width="33" Height="33" CornerRadius="3"/>
        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

How can I change content of the control in wpf? I've tried something like

```
<Control Template="{StaticResource Test}" BorderBrush="Black" Content="aa"></Control>
```

But when I do so I it says me that the property content is not recognized or it is not found.

Comment: Control is a base class and does not have Content property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `ContentControl` on its own to do what you want... to be clear, a `ContentControl` element has nothing to do with a `Control` element. It is used to display a data object and optionally apply a `DataTemplate` to the object. The `DataTemplate` is that part that you can customise:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeDataObject}" 
    ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SomeDataObjectTemplate}" />
```

...

In some `Resources` collection:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SomeDataObjectTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Prefix:SomeDataObject}">
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Your only other alternative is to declare a `UserControl` and expose certain parts of the markup as `DependencyProperty`s that you can data bind to from outside the control:

```
<Prefix:YourUserControl CustomContent="{Binding SomeDataObject}" />
```

Inside the control:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CustomContent, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Local:YourUserControl }}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Control does not derive from ContentControl it does not expose Content property. Take a look for more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).